# VS Single-file generators: how to add registry information? Run code on VS startup?

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to figure out how to get a single-file generator installed on VS2010. Previously I got it sort-of working on VS2013 after many hours of head-banging; in both cases the primary difficulty is **setting up the [registry entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166527.aspx)**. Apparently VSIX files [don't allow registry settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393694%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> You can use the VSIX format to package project and item templates,
>   Visual Studio Integration Packages, Managed Extensibility Framework
>   (MEF) components, toolbox controls, assemblies, and custom types. The
>   VSIX format uses strictly file-based deployment and does not support
>   writing to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), or to the system registry.
>   VSIX is the preferred deployment method for the extension types that
>   it supports.

My VS2013 solution involves the `CodeGeneratorRegistrationAttribute` and `ComVisible(true)` on the assembly, but after install, the extension doesn't work until the user runs `devenv.exe /setup` in Administrator mode. In VS2010, `CodeGeneratorRegistrationAttribute` does not exist in any of the SDK DLLs and simply adding the source code of CodeGeneratorRegistrationAttribute.cs to the project (as the [Single File Generator sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Single-File-Generator-94d856d4) does) doesn't seem to work (and I don't understand why the sample seems to expect it to work; .NET doesn't use [structural typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), after all, so how could this attribute possibly have any effect?)

If a VSIX cannot add registry settings directly, I think a reasonable substitute is to include some code that automatically runs on VS startup. That code could find out the path of the registry hive of the running VS version and add the necessary registry settings at that time. So I have three questions:

1. How can I cause a method written by me, inside my extension, to run when VS starts?
2. How can I get the path of the current VS registry hive?
3. Is there any other way to add the registry information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I gave up on making a VSIX to hold my single-file generator. I made a CodeProject article about [what I did instead](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686405/Writing-a-Single-File-Generator).

But back when I was still trying to make a VSIX file, [this blog post](http://codegoeshere.blogspot.ca/2009/11/vsix-with-vs2010-beta-2-sdk.html) came in handy.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with MSI-deployment? You can do anything from there. WiX has option to install VSIX packages pretty simply, just use the embedded element `<VSIXPackage>`. It also offers you to create new registry keys + you get registry key unistall for free. Note that you can elevate privileges, if needed.

Comment: Although I'd rather not go that route, if I did I would still have to be able to figure out where the VS registry hive is located. It seems there are several possible locations and I have yet to see a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

does your vsix have a class that extends [`Package`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.aspx)?

Add code in your Package's `Initialize` method that runs when your package is initialized.

To get to VS based registry stuff, see [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VSRegistry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsregistry.aspx)

Comment: `Package`? Which namespace? Anyway you can have the rep, I'm out of time to award it.

Comment: If you use the new project wizard to create a VSIX package that includes commands, it will generate a new type for you that extends visual studio's `Package` type.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.aspx

Comment: Ahh, this is unfortunate. I created a "Visual Studio Package" project with a menu command, and the package class is not initialized unless/until the user actually invokes the menu option.

Comment: Doable!  If you want it to load *all the time*, you can add    ``[ProvideAutoLoad(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]`` to your package attributes.  There's a similar guid `SolutionExists` if you want to load automatically when the user loads a solution.  But keep in mind, that does mean your stuff is loaded all the time, so keep it short and quick!

Comment: The Package+[ProvideAutoLoad] technique worked for me in VS2010, but malfunctioned in VS2012, VS2010 Express, and VS2013 Express (as detailed here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4e53cad-2fa3-45fc-8f6b-4d0bee3fb67c/vs-singlefile-generators-how-to-add-registry-information?forum=vsx), so I gave up on making a vsix and went with something completely different.

Comment: define "malfunctioned".  There are tons of things installed as VSIX, including a LOT of the in-box VS functionality.  As for express, express doesn't really allow extensions (hence being "express"), so that's a different issue altogether.

Comment: details are in the link I posted.